# Is there a way to detect when a certain entity is added to the database in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have an entity called X. Whenever a new `X` entry is added to the database in any part of my code (`db.Xs.Add(new_X_instance);`) I want to execute a specific sql query using entity framework. I wonder if this is possible. Just to let you know, I am not able to use SQL Server triggers.

Comment: "I am not able to use SQL Server triggers" Why not?  What does the SQL you want to run do?

Comment: My hosting service does not let me do this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override `SaveChanges()` method in `DbContext` class and in there you can get a list of new added entities.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var AddedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity>().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

    AddedEntities.ForEach(E => 
    {
        // Do whatever you like !
    });

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: what if I will need to read something from the db inside this method? Do I need to create a new instance of the my own DbContext class, like: `var db = new MyDbContext();  db.Cars.Where...` Or, should I use `base`?

Comment: @renakre since this method is in your DbContext you should use the base. also if you need to do "something" after the Entity has been added you can call "base.SaveChanges()" first and then write the ForEach loop for added Entities.

Comment: however, I cannot do this with base: `base.Cars.Where`, Cars is undefined. In other words, I cannot access the DbSet objects with `base`.

Comment: BTW, I had to add `.Select(i => i.Entity)` after the `Where` clause. Otherwise, I receive a conversion error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `ObjectContext`, like this:

```
var octx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext; // ctx is regular DbContext here
octx.ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged += (sender, item) =>
   {
       if (item.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Add) {
           // added
           var target = item.Element; // this is added entity
       }
   };
```

This will be called immediatly after you did your `Add`. Just remember that executing any sql *before* those entities were saved to database is not usually good idea.